# Database for a search engine

Tags: database, search-engine

I am thinking of developing a search engine, but have no idea about the backend that i could use efficiently. Please suggest me a database in which i can store thousands of records and query them in a time efficient manner. I am developing search engine for my own interest so, please dont give me any critics thoughts as usually found in similar question.

Thankyou

Comment: All depends on what you are searching for. Obviously the approach Bono uses is too slow...http://bit.ly/54Dlbs

Comment: Why not using a search engine like Lucene or similar instead of building one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Cloudant](https://cloudant.com/), which is a clustered/scalable deployment of Apache's [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).  CouchDB is part of the NoSQL initiative (it uses the filesystem instead of having storage abstracted by a database server) and is told to scale quite well, especially with Cloudant, though I haven't tried it myself.

Obviously with any DODB (document-oriented database, as Apache puts it) you're going to have to shift your concerns from solely memory and table indexing to include storage capacity, though using the filesystem means you're generally able to use less memory (as less information is stored *in* memory).  That's a broad generalization, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

For thousands of records, a standard rdbms will suffice.  For 100's of millions and beyond, you might want to look into alternatives.

But since you are doing it for your own interest, do one with each so you understand the differences.

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL** and **Full-text indexes** are a good solution to search inside thousands of records. When you scale up and get closer to 1 million rows, **MySQL full text** becomes slow and you will have to use another approach, like **Sphinx**.